# Тире или двоеточие в предложении. Как правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

Одним из дежурных был Дима — двадцатилетний парень с вьющимися, золотистыми волосами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из дежурных был Дима — двадцатилетний парень с вьющимися, золотистыми волосами.

Это распространенное приложение, которое в конце предложения обособляется тире.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:

2) **перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение:** *Объехали какую-то старую плотину, потонувшую в крапиве, и давно высохший пруд — глубокую яругу, заросшую бурьяном (Бун.); В лабазах в два ряда зияли широченные круглые ямы — деревянные чаны, глубоко врытые в землю (М. Г.); Выручил его велосипед — единственное богатство, накопленное за последние три года работы (Фел);*

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие ставить нельзя. Нет объяснения причин и перечисления.

Однозначно тире.

Тире обычно ставится, если вторая часть отвечает на вопрос `кто это?` / `что это?`

(это и есть наш случай)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что тире, так как это присоединительный оборот. Бывает, что вместо запятой перед присоед. оборотом ставится тире в таких случаях, как этот.
Здесь стоит тире, так как подразумевается пропущенная конструкция "а именно" :" Одним из дежурных был Дима, а именно...". То есть мы ставим тире из-за того, что пропущена эта самая конструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Для *двоеточия* нет никаких оснований; авторское тире *допустимо*, поскольку можно домыслить опущенную конструкцию (а был это...), а из стандартных соображений здесь нужна **запятая**. У Розенталя в "Справочнике" по орфографии и пунктуации находим:

> Обособляется приложение, стоящее **после имени собственного**:
>
> *Чемодан внесли кучер Селифан, **низенький человек в тулупчике**, и лакей Петрушка, малый лет тридцати в подержанном сюртуке* (Гоголь)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111